# Simple while loop returning a 'Call to undefined function' error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and am looking for some beginner help. I don't understand why this simple while loop is not working. I've checked for syntax errors with various variations and don't think that's the case.

The error says:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_assoc() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/basic-procedural-php-project/index.php:77 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/basic-procedural-php-project/index.php on line 77

The code is as follows:

```
<?php include 'db.php'; ?>

<?php
// Fetch data from db
$query = 'SELECT * FROM data';
$numbers = mysqli_query($con, $query);
?>

<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($numbers)) : ?>
            <p>whatever <?php echo $row['t_name'] ?></p>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
```

The database is as follows:

```
DB NAME: timesNumbers
DB TABLE NAME: data
COLUMNS: t_id, t_name, t_firstNo, t_secondNo
```

Can someone explain what the error means, the problem and how to fix it? I feel like it might be something basic that I'm not getting. Thanks for and help here.

Also the db.php file includes:

```
<?php

// Connect
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "timesNumbers");

// Test Connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Failed: '.mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
```

Comment: You're probably using PHP 7 and you haven't read this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Are you using version 7.*? The `mysql_*` family of functions have been removed in this version, having been deprecated for some time. You should use PDO instead.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Snap! :)

Comment: PHP version is 7.1.9

Comment: @DarraghEnright: Sorry, didn't mean to be rude.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware don't worry, you're not rude :)

Comment: ah ok, thank you. It worked after changing mysql_fetch_assoc to mysqli_fetch_assoc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix the usage of mysql and mysqli libraries/extensions. 
I guess you don't even have the mysql library/extension installed since you get that error.

You shouldn't use it anyway. Stick with mysqli or PDO.

To fetch data with mysqli, check the manual at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

PDO has my preference.

EDIT: Now you've mentioned the version of php is 7.1.9, it's for sure you don't have the mysql extension installed since its removed from php 7 after being deprecated for a long time.

Comment: ok thanks, is it ok to use mysqli_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_assoc?

Comment: *"I guess you don't even have the mysql library/extension installed since you get that error."* - [*"PHP version is 7.1.9 – user8758206"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53025692/simple-while-loop-returning-a-call-to-undefined-function-error#comment92953230_53025692). That would be a definite "no", since mysql_ has been deleted in that version of PHP.

Comment: ok, thank you. Will read up on that